# Maximum possible date in JPA

Tags: java, database, hibernate, date, jpa

Is there a way to represent the maximum (and minimum) possible date in JPA without being database specific? The JPA implementation should be then be able to translate it to the correct value according to the used dialect.

If not JPA an Hibernate specific solution would also be OK.

**Edit**

In an application we are using there are several named queries which test if a date is in a given range

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE somedate BETWEEN startdate AND end date
```

If the range is open (only startdate, or only enddate) it would be easier to use the maximum and minimum date that to have different queries with just a single comparison (this would require several changes in the existing application that I would like to avoid).

**Edit 2**

For the *not a real question* voters: the question is:

It is possible to query for the maximum possible date in a database agnostic way?

**Edit 3**

The application is storing dates as `java.util.Date` as follows

```
@Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
private java.util.Date someDate;
```

Comment: A comment on the close vote could be useful. Not pertinent? Duplicate? If it is a duplicate it would be not bad to mention a link.

Comment: I'm not the one who voted down nor voted to close, but why would you need this info, will you use it in a real application?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I edited the question with an explanation

Comment: If that's the case, why don't use `end` as '3000-01-01'? I know it's not the best answer, but I doubt the same application would be used for 1000 years.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It is what I am doing now but I was wandering if there was a *cleaner* solution

Comment: obviously a date can be stored as many things ... Long, String, DATETIME (or equiv)

Comment: @DataNucleus I updated the question with the used datatype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is no such feature (yet) to get the max/min date in DB neutral manner.

I'd suggest you to, base on the DBMS you are going to use, define corresponding constants in both Java and DB stored functions.

Therefore you can do something like:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Foo where date between :fromDate and :toDate");
query.setParameter("fromDate", DateConstants.MIN_DATE);
query.setParameter("toDate", DateConstants.MAX_DATE);
```

(I used to call that FOREVER and EPOCH  :P )

or even have HQL like this (if you have create stored function in DB)

`from Foo where date between MaxDate() and MinDate()`

Comment: Ok I will then have a function returning the max value according to the DB: according to the current DB I return the corresponding date (and if the DB is not known/supported I return something like 9999)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to define a database function that gives you that information.  Define it for each database vendor you plan to use.  Then use that function to obtain the max date for the "currently used" db.

Comment: Also a good idea, I don't know if it will be easier or not as the per product constants.

Comment: I think it depends how you define easy.

Comment: Exactly :-) In any case I noticed that working with `Date`s and JPA is not really an ideal world (too many DB-specific stuff as the handling of something smaller than a second on MySQL, the differences in the maximum and minimum values, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Best way to get maximum Date value in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743985/best-way-to-get-maximum-date-value-in-java). There should be no difference when using JPA or Hibernate as long as you use Date as java type. Exemple:

```
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Foo {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   long id;

   Date Bar;

   public void  setBar(Date bar) {
      this.bar = bar;
   }

   public Date getBar() {
      return bar;
   }
}

...

// An Entity
Foo foo;

// set minimum date
foo.setBar(new Date(0));

// set maximum date
foo.setBar(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));
```

Comment: Really? What do you get if you try to save it?

Comment: Simply because if it is for example mapped to a timestamp defined as 8 bytes counting in microseconds it will be 1000 bigger (Date(long values) is in milliseconds). But even if we divide by 1000 it will work for example on PostreSQL but a timestamp on Oracle cannot be larger than a date (and the maximum is 9999)

Comment: That is not an answer to my question. Your question was "Maximum possible date in JPA" right, so if my answer is not correct, (`new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE)` is NOT the maximum date), then I would like to know how you create a Date that is larger?

Comment: You don't create it since the DB will not support it. Of course I can create a larger date in Java but what for if I cannot persist it? I explicitly stated JPA in the question. If you want to use JPA and persist your Date objects you have constraints (which are sadly based on the DB implementation).