# Android notification for future date

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I was wondering is there a limit on how far in the future we can schedule a notification via `AlarmManager`?
I know this sounds weird but I was wondering if there is some kind of time limitation e.g. within 2 weeks

Answer (score 1):

No there is no time limitation as far as I can tell reading the API document. You can set the exact date by `setExact`.

[Alarm Clock API Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any limitation within the AlarmManager class on how far into the future an alarm can be set. When you call [setExact()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) or [setWindow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setWindow(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), the AlarmManager [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/AlarmManager.java#AlarmManager.setImpl%28int%2Clong%2Clong%2Clong%2Candroid.app.PendingIntent%2Candroid.os.WorkSource%2Candroid.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo%29) doesn't appear to do any validation beyond checking that the alarm date is in the future, and simply calls an IAlarmManager service to set the alarm.

```
private void setImpl(int type, long triggerAtMillis, long windowMillis, long intervalMillis,
            PendingIntent operation, WorkSource workSource, AlarmClockInfo alarmClock) {
        if (triggerAtMillis < 0) {
            /* NOTYET
            if (mAlwaysExact) {
                // Fatal error for KLP+ apps to use negative trigger times
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid alarm trigger time "
                        + triggerAtMillis);
            }
            */
            triggerAtMillis = 0;
        }

        try {
            mService.set(type, triggerAtMillis, windowMillis, intervalMillis, operation,
                    workSource, alarmClock);
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        }
    }
```

You will, however, be limited by the 64 bits in a long, as only a finite range of Dates can be represented. This means if you plan to set an alarm beyond [Sun Aug 17 07:12:55 UTC 292278994](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1743994/5144991), you may run into problems.

Another thing to consider is setting the alarm using [RTC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC) or [RTC_WAKE_UP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP), as this will affect whether the device is woken up by the alarm.

Comment: Why would the 64 bit be an issue? That date not a real issue right?

Answer (score 0):

Technically I believe there *is* a limit in the `set()` method of `AlarmManager` but it is so large, you can consider it limitless.

Consider this example:

```
    long futureInMillis = ...;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

The limit here for `futureInMillis` is `Long.MAX_VALUE` which is `(2^63)-1` or `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, but I am assuming you wont be needing to wait that long!