# Is a java long enough to store epoch time in microseconds?

Tags: java, timestamp, long-integer, epoch

Can I use a java long to store with reasonable precision the epoch time in microseconds with out any special signed to unsigned conversion tricks? If so how would I calculate the end date range?

This is the usual 8 byte date range:
-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

*UPDATE*

From suggestions to use:

```
new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE)
```

here is the end date for um:

```
new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE/1_000)

Sat Jan 09 20:00:54 PST 294247
```

And this is the end date using positive long values for nano seconds:

```
new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE/1_000_000)

Fri Apr 11 16:47:16 PDT 2262
```

Comment: So what are you asking about **micro** or **nano** seconds?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1743994/2970947
Is the answer for milliseconds. Divide the result of that by 1000000 to get the number for nanoseconds. `System.out.println(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE / 1000000L));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch why is it divide by 1000000 and not 1000? I though milliseconds and nanoseconds only differ by a factor of 1000 and the java Date() class would take in milliseconds.

Comment: Google: "nanoseconds per millisecond", Answer: "multiply the time value by 1e+6"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was just asking for microseconds. I said nano seconds accidentally.

Comment: It will be working fine until Friday, April 11, 2262 11:47:16.854 PM

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Nanos give only 3 centuries.
- Never roll-your-own time-keeping. **☛ Use [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) ☚**
- When exchanging date-time values, never use a count-from-epoch, use text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

## Doing the math

You must pick an [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). While [dozens of various epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) are used in the industry, one of the more common is often referred to as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): The first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Moments after that point are tracked using a positive number count, and prior moments use a negative number count.

Of course the length of a year varies by Leap Year, but we can easily approximate. Get the number of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) in a year using the `TimeUnit` class with its handy conversion methods.

Crunch some numbers.

```
long nanosPerDay = TimeUnit.DAYS.toNanos( 1L );
long nanosPerYear = ( long ) ( nanosPerDay * 365.25 );
long maximumYears = ( Long.MAX_VALUE / nanosPerYear );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "nanosPerDay: " + nanosPerDay );
System.out.println( "nanosPerYear: " + nanosPerYear );
System.out.println( "Long.MAX_VALUE: " + Long.MAX_VALUE + " provides for maximumYears: " + maximumYears );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/rF4dUz).

> nanosPerDay: 86400000000000

> nanosPerYear: 31557600000000000

> Long.MAX_VALUE: 9223372036854775807 provides for maximumYears: 292

So we get less than ±3 centuries before and after 1970. So this approach does work, if a few centuries is good enough for your app. At least you won’t be around to fix it when the calendar runs out. ;-)

## `Instant`

Fortunately we need not do this math ourselves.

Modern Java happens to come with the most advanced date-time handling framework available for business-oriented apps: The *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The `java.time.Instant` class uses a different strategy to tracking time. That class keeps a count of *whole* seconds before/after the epoch of 1970 UTC, plus a *separate* count of nanoseconds for the fractional-second of the moment.

Think of it as:

```
moment = ( whole-seconds + fractional-second ) ; // Since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
```

This enables a minimum/maximum of:

- [`Instant.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#MIN) = -1000000000-01-01T00:00Z
- [`Instant.MAX`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#MAX) = 1000000000-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z

Notice that *java.time* classes do carry a resolution of nanoseconds, while the legacy classes they supplanted (`Date`, `Calendar`, etc.) resolved to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).

For the gnarly details, see the [class JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#atZone(java.time.ZoneId)) and the OpenJDK [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/Instant.java) (in [Mercurial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial)).

Tip: The *java.time* classes are most appropriate to business-oriented purposes. If you are doing scientific, engineering, archeology, or history work, use other notations appropriate to the field, likely as `String` type.

## Granularity

Be aware that different computer systems use different granularities in their time-keeping.

As noted above, the *java.time* classes resolve to nanoseconds, for nine digits of a decimal fractional second. The legacy classes used milliseconds, for three digits of a decimal fractional second. Other systems, such as the [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database, use [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) for six digits of a decimal fractional second. When exchanging or comparing data across sytems, you may want to use the `truncatedTo` methods on various *java.time* classes.

Current conventional computer hardware clocks are accurate only to microseconds or grosser. They may report on nanoseconds but are not accurate to that degree. So, you will find that the `Instant.now()` method in Java 9, 10, & 11 capture the current moment to the microsecond (while the data type can *handle* nanos, it detects the *current* time in micros).

> Instant.now().toString(): 2019-01-23T12:34:56.123456Z

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).